# I need software to convert my video from mkv to mp4

Tags: video-editing

Basically, I want to merge videos.

One software to do so is avidemux.

However my video is in mkv and avidemux does not support that. I can only do so slowly.

So I want to reencode my video to mp4 and then use avidemux.

Now, what software I should use?

The original question is to reencode from mkv to mp4. I learn that you can actually convert without reencoding.

That's the stuff. How?

The software need to support hardware encoding. My video is of full had 60 fps high quality with almost lossless. I do not want to sacrifice quality.

Comment: avidemux can open mkv perfectly, in my experience. Its indexing takes about a minute per gigabyte I would say. Are you saying that you want software that allows you to start converting without having to wait?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it without re-encoding using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) by copying the codec from the original:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -codec copy out.mp4
```